# Docker Django GPIO Rasbian buster

Tags: docker, gpio

I am a complete beginner at Docker, so please do easy on me.

I am trying to deploy a Django project in a Docker container on a Raspberry Pi 3B, but I am running into a problem accessing the GPIO ports.

Every time I try to initialise Docker with “sudo docker-compose up”
I get the error: “RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!”

From what I have read, in order to get the Docker container to communicate with the GPIO ports the ‘user’ has to be a part of the ‘gpio’ group.

My questions are:

1. How can make the user a member of the GPIO group from either the Docker file or the docker-compose.yml?
2. Is there a better way of gaining access to the GPIO ports from Docker?

**Docker File:**

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp gcc libc-dev linux-headers
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN pip install RPi.GPIO
RUN pip install apscheduler
RUN apk del .tmp

RUN mkdir /poolproject

COPY ./poolproject /poolproject
WORKDIR /poolproject
COPY ./scripts /scripts

RUN chmod +x /scripts/*

RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/media
RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/static

RUN adduser -D user
RUN chown -R user:user /vol

RUN chmod -R 755 /vol/web
USER user

CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    privileged: true
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./poolproject:/poolproject
    command: sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
```

Comment: Can you try adding `RUN addgroup user gpio` after `RUN chown -R user:user /vol` in the dockerfile?

Comment: In general programs running in Docker containers can't access host hardware devices.  Can you run this program outside a container?

Comment: Yes, I've tried adding RUN addgroup user gpio, but it returns: addgroup: unknown group gpio
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c addgroup user gpio' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: David, the program is part pf a Django project and it works perfectly when run outside the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I apologize; I've retracted my earlier answer because I missed the fact that you already have `privileged: true` in your `docker-compose.yml`.  You have a different problem.

First, the error from `RPi.GPIO` is misleading: it doesn't really want access to `/dev/mem`; it wants access to `/dev/gpiomem`, which on the host has the following permissions:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /dev/gpiomem
crw-rw---- 1 root gpio 246, 0 Sep  7 09:02 /dev/gpiomem
```

Where the `gpio` group has gid `997`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ getent group gpio
gpio:x:997:pi
```

That means we need to arrange for your web service to run with gid `997` inside your container. We can do that by adding the `gpio` group inside your `Dockerfile`, and then making your `user` a member of that group:

```
RUN addgroup -g 997 gpio
RUN adduser -D -G gpio user
```

With this change, I'm able to run some my test code without errors. Additionally, it is no longer necessary to enable `privileged` mode; we can replace `privileged: true` in the `docker-compose.yml` with a `devices` entry to expose just the `/dev/gpiomem` device.

### Test environment

This is everything I used to test the situation.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp gcc libc-dev linux-headers
RUN pip install RPi.GPIO

RUN addgroup -g 997 gpio
RUN adduser -D -G gpio user

RUN mkdir -p /scripts
RUN chown -R user:gpio /scripts
COPY gpiotest.py /scripts/gpiotest.py
RUN chmod 755 /scripts/gpiotest.py

CMD python /scripts/gpiotest.py
USER user
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    devices:
      - /dev/gpiomem:/dev/gpiomem
```

This is my `gpiotest.py` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import time

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    val = GPIO.input(17)
    print('value:', val)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Hi Larsks, many thanks for your detailed explanation. I am having trouble running your example. The "mkdir - p /scripts" does not create the directory and inevitably "docker-compile up" fails with an error. app_1  | python: can't open file '/scripts/gpiotest.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied
docker-test_app_1 exited with code 2.

Comment: I can't envision a situation in which that `mkdir` would fail. If you want to pastebin somewhere the output of `docker-compose build --no-cache` (and I guess also the output of `docker-compose up`) I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Thank you again Larsks, here it is:  https://pastebin.pl/view/b8f47c46

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem on my Pi. What the result of running `docker-compose run app ls -ld /scripts /scripts/gpiotest.py`? Feel free to put the result in another pastebin, since it's not possible to put multi-line output in a comment. I would suggest we move this conversation to chat, but [that feature appears to be buggy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353966/unable-to-grant-access-to-a-chatroom-to-a-low-reputation-user-trying-to-move-a).

Comment: You should be able to use [this room if needed](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221153/discussion-on-answer-by-larsks-docker-django-gpio-rasbian-buster).

Comment: @user12231454 let's move this conversation over to the chat room that Jon has created; this way you can put output and config samples directly in the chat rather than using an external pastebin.

Comment: The issue was permissions on the `gpiotest.py` script. Adding an explicit `chmod` to the `Dockerfile` corrected the problem.

Comment: Larsks, just a quick note to thank you for all of your help, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I still get "RuntimeError: This module can only be run on a Raspberry Pi!". I checked the gid of gpio on the host, it's 997.

Comment: both of those parameters are yielding "... is ambiguous"

Comment: Both of which parameters?